# How to create a class and pass objects as arguements to method in perl?

Tags: perl, oop

this is my code

```
       public class TKomplex
   {
       public double real;
       public double imag;
   }

           public TKomplex ksum(TKomplex a, TKomplex b)
           {
               TKomplex res;
               res.real = a.real + b.real;
               res.imag = a.imag + b.imag;
              return (res);
           }


           public TKomplex kprod(TKomplex a, TKomplex b)
           {
               TKomplex res;
               res.real = a.real * b.real - a.imag * b.imag;
               res.imag = a.real * b.imag + a.imag * b.real;
               return (res);
           }
```

How to code this in perl? How to create a class and pass objects as arguements to method in perl?

Comment: why class and objects?  neither is in your existing code.

Comment: oops...edited... n I am new o perl..Is it not possible to pass TKomplex as aguement in perl?

Comment: Perl's native object orientation is quite different from how other languages work. There will be no way around *understanding* the object model of the source, and *redesign* it in Perl's model. Reengineering, in short. Not much fun...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way, using Moo objects:

File TKomplex.pm:

```
package TKomplex;
use Moo;

has real => (
    is => 'rw',
);
has imag => (
    is => 'rw',
);

sub ksum {
    my ($a, $b) = @_;
    my $res = TKomplex->new;
    $res->real( $a->real + $b->real );
    $res->imag( $a->imag + $b->imag );
    return $res;
}

sub kprod {
    my ($a, $b) = @_;
    my $res = TKomplex->new;
    $res->real( $a->real * $b->real - $a->imag * $b->imag );
    $res->imag( $a->real * $b->imag + $a->imag * $b->real );
    return $res;
}

1;
```

Example use:

```
use TKomplex;
my $val = TKomplex->new( real => 3, imag => -2 );
my $ksum = TKomplex::ksum( $val, $val );
print "real: ", $ksum->real, " imag: ", $ksum->imag, "\n";
```

Note that ksum and kprod are not methods, they are subroutines.  If you want to call them as class methods, say `TKomplex->ksum(...)` and change them to take a `$class` parameter before `$a` and `$b`.

Without Moo, remove the use Moo and has clauses and add:

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
sub new {
    my ($class, %object) = @_;
    return bless \%object, $class;
}
sub real {
    my $self = shift;
    if (@_) {
        $self->{real} = shift;
    }
    else {
        $self->{real}
    }
}
sub imag {
    my $self = shift;
    if (@_) {
        $self->{imag} = shift;
    }
    else {
        $self->{imag}
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u...bt im getting error like cant locate moo.pm

Comment: I can do without moose ,cant I?

Comment: mooseless example added, but you are better off installing Moo or Moose.

Comment: Thank you.. bt i am getting error like this   Can't locate object method "new" via package "TKomplex" at test1.pl line 2.

Comment: You need to add the new code somewhere after the `package` declaration.

Comment: right after the package declaration, yes.

Comment: YES!! But still I am getting that error??

Comment: put your entire current code at the end of your question